# awk searching for characters recursively

Tags: search, awk, grep

I would like to search for a string within multiple files recursively.

I have used grep before, and it works fine.

grep -r SearchString .

But I hear awk is much faster. So I am using the below command but it just prints out everything on the file?

```
awk 'If ($0 ~/SearchString/) {print $0} ' /path/*
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and sample of output in your post in code tags and let us know on same.

Comment: input: awk 'If ($0 ~/Hello/) {print $0} ' /Desktop/MyFolder/*

output: CAT of everything within Myfolder.

Comment: So you want to print a line with filename if a match is found?

Comment: no, I would like to print the line where the searchstring is found within the files...

Comment: awk is not faster than grep

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88503/using-grep-vs-awk

Comment: Could you add some more information about what you attempt to do? Which files are you searching (XML, ASCII, source code), are these the only files in the subdirectory, what is your final goal? How many files are there, and how much data is there (MB, GB, TB)?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are a bit off. Awk is a tool that is designed for working on a predefined set of files. So it does not have any knowledge of *recursive fileprocessing*.

On a single file, one would o:

```
awk '/regex/' file1 file2
```

and this would print all lines of file1 and file2 which match `regex`. This, however, might not be what you want, as it does not give you any information which line belongs to which file, in contrast, to `grep -E 'regex' file1 file2`. To achieve this, you already need to start adding stuff, making your awk a bit less comfortable:

```
awk '/regex/{print FILENAME,":",$0}' file1 file2
```

If you want to go recursive, you will need to use `find` for this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 awk '/regex/{print FILENAME":", $0}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Actually after performing a few tests. I see that awk uses 50% of the cpu while grep uses around 12%! Unfortunately its still slow, and hasn't solved my issue of wanting to search recursively fast!

Comment: On another note. I have looked into elastic search. But my problem with that is indexing many different types of files is alot of work, and will take a huge amount of time.

Comment: Do you just want to know the files that contain the string, or do you also need the strings? You might be interested in GNU parallel for this. If you just want to have the FILENAMES of the files that contain the string, you should use `grep -lr 'string' path/`

Comment: I require the string within the files. I have used grep. It works with no issues! But is very slow! :(

Comment: @kay.keys Do you need to grep through all the files in the subdirectories, or do you know that only certain files are of interest. Example, you want to search for the string 'foo' in all files of the form `*.abc`, but there are also many files of the type `*.xyz`. You should try to exclude those from the recursive search. Grep is a very optimised tool, and very much tuned for what it is supposed to do. You will not find a lot of faster options. The only thing you might do is to parallelised it using GNU `parallel`, but you should realise that you are very limited by your HD speed.

Comment: @kay.keys If you would give us more details of what you exactly attempt to do, we might help you out in a much more effective way.